# Custom thread pool C# issue

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

So, I have a custom thread pool which receives a maximum number of threads and you can queue items in it. The pool will execute the items in queue. The problem is that the behaviour of this pool is always different. I have created a test that gives X number of operations to this pool and waits for the pool to finish the work (there is a limit for this waiting, but the limit is enough for all the operations to end successfully). The problem is that sometime the test returns a "success" response but most of the times it exceeds it's time limit and/or does not process all the operations.

Code:

CustomThreadPool.cs

```
    public class CustomThreadPool : IDisposable
    {
        #region Private Members

        private readonly Thread m_checkThread;

        #endregion

        #region Public Properties

        public int MaxNumberOfThreads { get; set; }
        private readonly object m_lock = new object();
        private int m_currentNumberOfThreads;
        public int CurrentNumberOfThreads
        {
            get
            {
                lock (m_lock)
                {
                    return m_currentNumberOfThreads;
                }
            }
            private set
            {
                lock (m_lock)
                {
                    m_currentNumberOfThreads = value;
                }
            }
        }
        public ConcurrentQueue<WorkItem> QueuedItems { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        public CustomThreadPool(int maxNumberOfThreads)
        {
            MaxNumberOfThreads = maxNumberOfThreads;

            QueuedItems = new ConcurrentQueue<WorkItem>();
            m_checkThread = new Thread(CheckThread);
            m_checkThread.Start();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public Methods

        public void QueueItem(object argument, Action<WorkItem> method, string token = "")
        {
            QueuedItems.Enqueue(new WorkItem { Argument = argument, Method = method, Token = token });
        }

        public List<WorkItem> Stop()
        {
            m_checkThread.Abort();
            List<WorkItem> result = new List<WorkItem>();
            while (QueuedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                WorkItem wi;
                QueuedItems.TryDequeue(out wi);
                if (wi != null)
                    result.Add(wi);
            }
            CurrentNumberOfThreads = 0;
            return result;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Private Methods

        // ReSharper disable once FunctionNeverReturns
        private void CheckThread()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (CurrentNumberOfThreads >= MaxNumberOfThreads || QueuedItems.Count == 0)
                {
                    Thread.Yield();
                }

                int availableThreads = MaxNumberOfThreads - CurrentNumberOfThreads;

                List<WorkItem> toBeProcessed = new List<WorkItem>();

                for (var i = 0; i < availableThreads; i++)
                {
                    WorkItem wi;
                    QueuedItems.TryDequeue(out wi);

                    if (wi != null)
                    {
                        toBeProcessed.Add(wi);
                    }
                }

                foreach (WorkItem item in toBeProcessed)
                {
                    CurrentNumberOfThreads++;
                    item.ExecutingThread = new Thread(ProcessItem);
                    item.ExecutingThread.Start(item);
                }

                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
        }

        private void ProcessItem(object wi)
        {
            WorkItem item = (WorkItem)wi;
            item.Method.Invoke(item);
            CurrentNumberOfThreads--;
            item.ExecutingThread.Abort();
        }

        #endregion

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        private void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                m_checkThread.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
```

Test:

```
private List<int> EndedOperations = new List<int>();
private List<int> StartedOperations = new List<int>();

public void CheckThreadPool()
    {
        int workTime = 100;
        int numberOfOperations = 100;
        int numberOfThreads = 10;
        int cycles = numberOfOperations / numberOfThreads;
        int totalTime = workTime * 2 * cycles;
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        CustomThreadPool pool = new CustomThreadPool(numberOfThreads);

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfOperations; i++)
        {
            pool.QueueItem(new WorkInfo(i, workTime), DoWork);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(workTime);
        bool queueEmpty = false, operationsDone = false;
        while (pool.CurrentNumberOfThreads > 0 && sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < totalTime)
        {
            if (pool.QueuedItems.Count == 0 && !queueEmpty)
            {
                queueEmpty = true;
                Debug.WriteLine("Queue emptied at: {0}, operations left: {1}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, numberOfOperations - EndedOperations.Count);
            }
            if (EndedOperations.Count == numberOfOperations && !operationsDone)
            {
                operationsDone = true;
                Debug.WriteLine("Operations done at: {0}, number of threads: {1}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, pool.CurrentNumberOfThreads);
            }
            Thread.Yield();
        }
        sw.Stop();
        pool.Dispose();
        Thread.Sleep(workTime);
        Debug.WriteLine("Test ended with {0} unprocessed operations", numberOfOperations - EndedOperations.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfOperations; i++)
        {
            if (!EndedOperations.Contains(i))
                Debug.WriteLine("Operation {0} was not fully processed", i);
            if (!StartedOperations.Contains(i))
                Debug.WriteLine("Operation {0} has never started", i);
        }
        Assert.IsTrue(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < totalTime,
            string.Format(@"The pool did not stop in useful time. 
                                Remaining threads : {0}
                                Remaining queued items : {1}
                                Remaining operations: {2}",
                                pool.CurrentNumberOfThreads, pool.QueuedItems.Count, numberOfOperations - EndedOperations.Count));
        Assert.IsTrue(pool.QueuedItems.Count == 0,
            string.Format(@"Not all items were processed. 
                                Remaining : {0}
                                Processing time : {1}",
                                pool.QueuedItems.Count, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds));
    }

    private void DoWork(WorkItem wi)
    {
        WorkInfo info = (WorkInfo)wi.Argument;
        try
        {
           StartedOperations.Add(info.Id);
            Thread.Sleep(info.TestTime);
            EndedOperations.Add(info.Id);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("id: {0}, ex: {1}", info.Id, ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

I'm assuming that the problem might come from a shared resource but I can't figure out which one.

Thank you.

Comment: This question is very broad and both the threadpool class and the test class are full of oversights and fragile code.  If you need a threadpool, the .NET framework provides one for you.  If you are interested in writing one yourself as an exercise, I suggest you study the .NET implementation and understand it first. http://tinyurl.com/k6d9l6v  In fact, this isn't even really a threadpool.  You're creating threads as work is added - a pool is meant to keep a number of threads alive and ready to work.  This is little better than just spinning off a thread directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you put a `lock` on the assignment of `CurrentNumberOfThreads`, that is no enough because your increment and decrement operations are not atomic.

You should use atomic operations provided by `Interlocked` class:

Replace

```
CurrentNumberOfThreads++;
```

With

```
System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref m_CurrentNumberOfThreads);
```

and

```
CurrentNumberOfThreads--;
```

with

```
System.Threading.Interlocked.Decrement(ref m_CurrentNumberOfThreads);
```

And another thing to notice: never `abort` the threads like this. Try to make some way for them to be informed and exit gracefully.

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my life. One more question though. While running the tests I have observed that depending on the available number of threads for the custom thread pool the test takes to long. Now I know that if the process has to many threads it might be less optimum, but how can I find the range of numbers of threads(depending on the machine's processor) to initialise the custom thread pool?   Thank you very much!

Comment: That depends on many parameters. I suggest you place some counters on your test and adjust the number of threads then you can interpolate the results and find the optimum point.